# Why serializers instantiated when the Django starts?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am using Django rest framework, and I am confused that the serializer will be instantiated when Django starts up.

How can I stop this behavior?

```py
class MySerializer(ModelSerializer):
    def __init__(self):
        print('hello!') # <= this called when django starts!!
```

#### P.S.

The cause was the Serializer is invoked as other serializer's class field property (as nested field). So `MySerializer` is instantiated when `AnotherSerializer` is imported as module.

```py
class AnotherSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    some_nested_field = MySerializer()
```

So,,, what I want to know is how can I instantiate `MySerializer` only when the actual request arrives, not when the module is loaded?

Comment: Are you using it in any view where it may be instantiated? You could inspect frames why it is called using e.g. PyCharm debugger or `inspect` module.

Comment: Thanks. I tried `inspect` and figured out that the serializer is instantiated when it is imported from the view file. But it's not instantiated explicitly. 

Just importing some class instantiates class??

Comment: I think they shouldn't; are you able to show the view where it is probably instantiated? Maybe some viewset with `serializer_class` and accidentally added parentheses?

Comment: Oh,,, You are right. This serializer is used as other serializer's nested serializer(as Class level property). And it's instantiated at there. I should find another way to run the process... anyway, thanks a lot!